# Change color of Evince Document Viewer search results?

Tags: evince

Is it possible to change the colors that Evince Document Viewer uses to highlight search results?

Please take a look at the screenshot example below. Personally, I find the the selected (bottom) result very difficult to visually distinguish from the other non-selected (top) result.

Instead, I would prefer to give both two different colors.

[image]

Comment: 2022, still an ugly "selected-like" color...

Comment: I have no idea how to do it, but [changing the source code may work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165863/how-to-force-custom-color-scheme-when-using-inverted-colors-in-evince)